# Getting correct but slightly different value deserializing a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

I'm running the following code.

```
Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
  {"monkey", "donkey"},
  {"wonkey", 1337}
};
string serial = JsonSerializer.Serialize(input);
var output = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(serial);
```

The serialized value is `"{\"monkey\":\"donkey\",\"wonkey\":1337}"`. However, inspecting the original, I see

> {[monkey, donkey]}
> {[wonkey, 1337]}

while the recreation looks like so:

> {[monkey, ValueKind = String : "donkey"]}
> {[wonkey, ValueKind = Number : "1337"]}

and I have no idea how to "correct" it. The unit test fails miserably, of course, as it sees different values. For a human, it's pretty obvious that it's the same value. Or, rather, the same'ish.

I suspected that it's got to do with the conversion of `object` that's actually an integer and/or string. I tried the sample below, which produces similar operation but couldn't reproduce the deviation, as the recreation was precisely equal original.

```
object original = "original";
string serialization = JsonSerializer.Serialize(original);
object recreation = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(serialization);
```

The unit test is asserted the following way. The last assertion fails.

```
Assert.Equal(input.Count, output.Count);
Assert.NotSame(input, output);
foreach (string key in input.Keys)
  Assert.True(output.ContainsKey(key));
foreach (string key in input.Keys)
  Assert.Equal(input[key], output[key]);
```

Comment: Unit test the content of the dictionary instead of the Json string.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm not sure I understand. What I'm doing in the actual code **is indeed** a unit test and I check for the individual keys (which asserts correctly) and the values connected to them (which fails due to the described issue). What did I miss?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Please view the edit. I amended the assertions. Initially, I left omitted them aiming for the minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: that's because of 'Dictionary<string, object>' type.  Best way is to check the content of the dictionary during unit test or use Newtonsoft.Json to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: @BinodMahto Would you like to elaborate, please. The unit test I'm running checks if the recreated entity is the same as the original. What did you refer to by "during unit test"? What I need funcionality-wise is that the recreated entity is precisely equal on all the elements to the original. It doesn't get that way and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Change the last Assert statement to this and your problem will be solved as you need to validate the content.
Assert.AreEqual(input[key].ToString(), output[key].ToString());

Comment: @BinodMahto Two FUQs on that. (1) why do I need to do that in the key? It seems unnecessary in my case. (2) The update you suggest may make the unit test work out. However, the deserialization will still produce a different result than the original. I suspect that the alteration of the outcome should be introduced in the serialization process rather than in the unit test. What do you think? (Also, it seems that `ToString()` doesn't change the outcome to the original string neither...)

Comment: Probably not as the System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer is designed to work in that way with type 'object' and this would be same problem even with other serialization package too (i.e. NewtonSoft) as they will use their default type to typecast the object type. In NewtonSoft, your object type will be typecast to 'long' while desterilizing (recreation).
So the best solution is to always typecast while comparing in this case.

Comment: Seems to be a customer deserialization, you can opt to use Custom Converters for same. More Details on [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#registration-sample---converters-collection)

Comment: @Vikas I've read the article. Still feeling a bit uncertain, though. Are you suggesting that I introduce a set of custom converters (one for each type that I bounce around in my Dictionary<string,object> instance)? Or are you suggesting a single custom converter that works on the whole dictionary? Feel free to give a brief sample. Perhaps that will make things more clear.

Comment: Note that the entries in a dictionary are not ordered consistently because of the hash table used internally. With mstest use [CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) to compare the collections without considering the order. The [CollectionAssert.AreEqual Method]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) on the other hand, considers the order.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I agree that the dictionary can have arbitrary order of elements (or, rather, lacks an order, being sort of a bag of labeled data pieces). That said, I'm not certain how it relates to my question. The keys are picked in a certain order in the original dictionary and the values are compared by each key. The actual order in the recreated dictionary is of no relevance, as long as the keys are unique (which I believe they need to be in a dictionary<A,B>). What am I missing, please?

Comment: The idea is to convert the original dict to JSON, convert it back to a new dictionary and then compare the content of the two dictionaries. I.e., the exact format of the JSON string would not matter.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is correct that the format of the (serialized) dict in JSON doesn't matter. However, I still don't see how it relates to my question. I fear that I didn't ask sufficiently clearly. The restored dictionary (from the serialized JSON) is not **precisely** the same as the original one. Investigating the individual elements shows the deviation as shown in the question. The original `donkey` becomes `ValueKind = String : "donkey"`, It's semantically the same but due to inboxing in `object`, exhibits a different annotation. Is it more apparent now or did I miss the point?

Comment: boxing applies only to value types. String will not be affected. But since the value is typed as `object`, the numbers will always be stored as boxed in the dictionary. So, I'm not sure where the difference comes from. Could it be that the number is returned as `long` or `decimal`?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I can't tell, to be honest. What I know is that if you run the sample in the question, you will get the same unexpected result as I did (given that there's no discrepancies between out systems). Give it a try. That's what's the minimal viable examples are for. Otherwise, we're just speculating in theoretical terms. And from that aspect, I do agree - that shouldn't happen. If you execute the sample, perhaps you'll notice something that I missed and kill the mystery. I'm fine with that.   :)

Comment: I did, and the deserialized values in the dictionary are of type `JsonElement`. I thought what you called "recreation" was a Json text; however, it was the content of the Dictionary as displayed by the VS debugger. [Migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json - .NET / Deserialization of object properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialization-of-object-properties) says "System.Text.Json stores a boxed JsonElement for both primitive and complex values whenever deserializing to Object"

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'll check the link you provided. Perhaps I'll learn something new, which is always a good thing. However, I'm not entirely clear on your point, sorry for being slow. When I run `AssertEqual(original,recreation)`, I get error due to the contents being different. I'm trying it on individual elements too, iterating through the key-value pairs in the dictionary. Are you able to compare those two (before and after) and get them to equal? Or can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: This happens because the original contains `string` or `int` values, while recreation contains `JsonElement` values wrapping the real value. The serializer just doesn't do it right. Newtonsoft.Json does it better, however it might return `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for your comments. Regrettably, I can't say I understand your point. It seems to me that you discuss the ordering of elements, the JSON structure influence, the type of the deserialized output and other serializators. All that correct but how does it relate to the issue at hand (including the presented answer resolving it), please? I'm missing how it all fits into that, hence fearing that my formulation isn't sufficiently clear. Please explain.

Comment: Forget my original comment on the ordering etc. Meanwhile, I have come to the conclusion that objects of type `JsonElement` are returned instead of strings and int.  `someDictEntry.Value.GetType().Name` returns `"JsonElement"`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes So, am i to understand that you second the opinion of Vikas' answer suggestion a custom converter implementing a set of conditionals like `if(r.TokenType==JsonTokenType.Xxx)return reader.GetXxx();` (roughly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line failed because of mismatch of datatype `JsonElement` and `int`.
We can use converters to convert to specific type.

Just for example (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-basic-converter) for details).

```
public class ObjectConverter: JsonConverter<object>
{
  public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
      return reader.GetInt32();

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
      return reader.GetString();

    return reader.GetString();
  }

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
  }
}
```

And use this converter in deserialization.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new ObjectConverter());
var output = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(serial, options);
```

Comment: So, after a quick glance at your sample, I sense that I will end up creating e.g. `DateTimeToStringConverter`, `StringToStringConverter` etc. I'm willing to try that (although a generic solution would definitely be preferred but I'll look into that eventually, later on). However, I don't see how it applies to **de**serialization. Are you saying that it will work automagically based in the converter definition (the `Write()` method to be precise)?

Comment: As this is a specific scenario where Dictionary with value as object has to be correctly converted to a specific int type. That's why I only mentioned deserialization, But if you have requirement for any translation for other DataTypes, will need adaptations in Read and Write operations.

Comment: Oh, so stupid... I just realized what my confusion was. In my dumb head I connected `Read()` as the method that we use when we serialize (we read from the source) and `Write()` when we deserialize (we write to the receiving program). But it's **of course** the other way around. And I assume (haven't checked that yet) that `JsonTokenType` is precisely what is fetched from `ValueKind = Whatever`. Now, I only need to implement a bunch of if-statements to cover the types I'm converting from. Neat, mate. Thanks. It's +1 and a green check.

Comment: I'll probably poke around and reformat/adhere in your sample to make it from great to perfect. I hope it's not taking too much liberty. And it will certainly help other slow-thinkers like me in the future.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this FUQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625853/unable-to-breakpoint-on-custom-serialization). It's based on your answer to this one. (I also took the liberty to format it a bit to make it ever better. I hope you don't mind.)